# How to create a docker-compose for two containers that are forwarding and requesting between each other?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers where one is the web application (web-app) and the other is an authentication web application (auth-app).

I go to web-app and get forwarded to the auth-app and the auth-app will forward me back to web-app. The web-app will then send another request to auth-app to verify.

I tried setting aliases (web-app, auth-app) but when web-app forwards me i get "https://auth-app:8443/..." which the host does not recognize.

Is there a way to do this via docker-compose?

compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  auth-app:
    image: auth-app:1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    networks:
      thenetwork:
        aliases:
            - auth-app
  web-app:
    image: web-app:1
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"
      - "8445:8443"
    networks:
      thenetwork:
        aliases:
            - web-app
networks:
    thenetwork:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting to `https://auth-app:8443`, forward to `https://localhost:8443`. Likewise, from the `auth-app` to the `web-app`, redirect to `http://localhost:8282` or `https://localhost:8445`

Comment: @Turing85 I tried that too. Since web-app will be requesting to auth-app, localhost:8445 is now returning a 404. I'm unable to change this to different things since we're using a library and I was hoping it was possible.

Comment: @Turing85 `localhost` **always** resolves to `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, so redirecting to `localhost` will redirect both apps back to themselves (and therefore fail).

Comment: @KonradBotor that depends where the resolve takes place. On the backend, you are right. On the frontend, it will be resolved by the client and result in the expected behaviour. And redirects are normally resolved on the client-side.

Comment: The redirect works if i use localhost since it resolved on the host side but since web-app container tries to request from auth-app with localhost:8445 it is a 404. Is there a way to forward ports? localhost:8445 -> auth-app:8445 from the web-app container?

Comment: @Kebs Isn't auth-app listening on 8443 and 8080, not 8445?

Comment: @KonradBotor Yes. Mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

since your apps seem to need to communicate via the same url on the backend as well as in the frontend, I would say use the actual hostname or IP of the host instead of localhost.  Localhost will work when the app redirects on the frontend, but when redirecting in the backend localhost will refer to the container trying to do the redirect.

Comment: Yes. I had used aliases in a network. But the aliases do not resolve on the host side. I am unable to change the configuration of the forward and the request to use different urls to resolve the auth-app.

Comment: Did you try using your host's IP or hostname in the redirect? BTW, the aliases you specified in your Compose file are created by default, there's no need to specify them manually.

Comment: I tried changing it to the host IP. There is also a redirect to the auth-app which will use the host ip (docker network host ip). That redirect did not work since the host will try to resolve in a different network.